# Laravel: how to paginate a ' One to Many ' Relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, pagination, relationship

Ummm I have to Tables in my database Bus and Station, they have One to Many Relationship, Here is the problem with Scenario-

1. One Station can have many Bus.
2. with 5 to 10 bus no need to paginate, but what if Station has 100 or 1000 buses. this approach is horrible.

and here's what I did...

**Bus Relationship with Station**

```
public function station()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Station::class);
}
```

**Statation Relationship with Bus**

```
public function bus()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bus::class);
}
```

and here what I did in the **Index Controller**

```
//  getting ther user id
$id= Sentinel::getUser()->id;

// fiding the statioin_id of that user_id and assigning it to variable
$user = User::find($id);
$s_id = $user->station_id; 

//  fiding the station which tht station_id belongs to and assign it to variable
$station = Station::find($s_id);
$stations_id = $station->id;

//  getting buses of that specific station_id we just get and paginating it
$stationbus = Station::find($stations_id)->bus()->paginate();

return view('bus.index')->with('buses', $stationbus->bus);
```

and this the **Index View**

[image]

when I execute the above code this error will pop up

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$bus

and Again, my code works fine except the pagination part.

Comment: In your `->with()` method, shouldn't `$stationbus->bus` just be `$stationbus`?

Comment: @TimLewis how did I miss that! thanks, man, you saved my day.

Comment: No worries. It happens :) The error is a little vague if you don't know what a `LengthAwarePaginator is`, but generally when you see "undefined property X", look for `$something->X`, and you should find the culprit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Here, is some of my proposals to make your code better:**

In `Station` model:

```
public function buses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Bus::class);
}
```

the method name should be `buses()` as it's returning many `buses`, not single `bus`

Then your controller code can be re-written as below:

```
$user= Sentinel::getUser();//So, you have the user 

$station = Station::find($user->station_id);
//We don't need to query again, we already have the station. So...

$buses = $station->buses()->paginate();

return view('bus.index', compact('buses'));
```

Thus, it's more readable, compact and less query to execute.

Comment: I don't think this will do the magic. Our friend up there @Tim gave me a little hand which was a simple mistake I made, but anyway thanks, brother.